# How to change color to a specific part of a loaded gltf model in three.js?

Tags: javascript, threejs-editor

`Hello, I'm getting acquainted with three js. I don't quite understand how to change the color of my model. I tried textureLoader, MeshPhongMaterial. If I specify something, the model disappears. I have MeshBasicMaterial, but it doesn't seem to work.. Tell me where I messed up?

```
>! function init() {let container = document.querySelector('.container');//Sceneconst scene = new THREE.Scene()scene.background = new THREE.Color("#E2DFE1");
//Cameraconst camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);camera.position.set(600, 5, 1)//renderconst renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)container.appendChild(renderer.domElement)/*let plain;{plain = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0, 0),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "#E2DFE1"}))plain.reciveShadow = true;plain.position.set(0, -1, 0)plain.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);scene.add(plain)}*/// Model{//material/*const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();meshMaterial.shading = THREE.FlatShading;material.color.set('#9457EB');*/}{const loader = new GLTFLoader();loader.load('./model/scene.gltf', gltf => {var model = gltf.scene;     scene.add(model);}, function (error) {console.log('Error: ' + error)}   )}{//Fogconst color = '#CFCFCF';const near = 100;const far = 1500;scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(color, near, far); }{const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1)light.position.set(2, 5, -15)light.lookAt(0, -1, 0)scene.add(light)}{const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1)light.position.set(2, 0, 5)light.lookAt(0, 1, 0)scene.add(light)}RectAreaLightUniformsLib.init();{const rectLight = new THREE.RectAreaLight(0xffffff, 1, 100, 100);rectLight.position.set(-10,0,0)rectLight.rotation.y = Math.PI + Math.PI/4;scene.add(rectLight)}{const rectLight = new THREE.RectAreaLight(0xffffff, 1, 100, 100);rectLight.position.set(10,0,0)rectLight.rotation.y = Math.PI - Math.PI/4;scene.add(rectLight)}//OrbitControlsconst controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);controls.autoRotate = true;controls.autoRotateSpeed = 0.5;controls.enableDamping = true; //Resizewindow.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false)function onWindowResize() {camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;camera.updateProjectionMatrix();renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)}// Animatefunction animate() {    requestAnimationFrame(animate)controls.update();renderer.render(scene, camera)}animate() }init()
```

I tried textureLoader, MeshPhongMaterial`